# Visualforce Email Template does not always merge fields

Tags: apex, visualforce, email, process-builder, email-template

**BACKGROUND**

I have a Visualforce email template does not always fully merge correctly.

**Scenario 1: Via Setup - SUCCESS**

Using the *Send Test and Verify Merge Fields* button in Setup, the email merges and sends correctly.

**Scenario 2: Manually trigger Process Builder - SUCCESS**

When I update the `Booking__c` status to *Confirmed* it triggers a Process Builder process which calls an `InvocableMethod`  and the email merges and sends correctly.

**Scenario 3: RestResource Controller triggers Process Builder - FAILING**

1. Request comes into a `RestResource` controller, the apex code updates an `Invoice__c` object
2. Triggers a Process Builder process, which calls an `InvocableMethod` which updates the `Booking__c` status to *Confirmed*
3. Triggers a Process Builder process to send the emails via the same `InvocableMethod` used in Scenario 2, but the `relatedTo` fields do not merge.

The `recipient` fields merged correctly, but the `relatedTo` fields do **not**.

**Testing**

I added this code to see if the `relatedTo` object wasn't available to the template at the point of merging:

```
<p>
{!recipient.Id }
</p>
<p>
{!relatedTo.Id }
</p>
<p>
{!relatedTo.Name }
</p>
```

And the IDs and NAME **do appear** in the failing email, but the rest of the merge fields do **not**.

> 0034E00000hn5OfQAI
>
> a0C4E000003YmGlUAK
>
> APPT-000367

Additionally, I tried replacing the *broken* email template with a working template, and that also failed to merge correctly.

Therefore, I am assuming it is **not** an issue with the email template markup or merge fields.

But rather an issue with the chaining of the Process Builder processes and Apex calls...

**QUESTION**

Why would the `relatedTo` fields not merge correctly in **Scenario 3**?

Comment: Can you post email template code, editing your question. I think in the 3rd scenario, data is not committed, before sending the email which is asynchronous process

Comment: @SantanuBoral all the information that is being merged into the email already exists.  None of the merge fields are recently added data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by the permissions of the `Site Guest User` which is hosting the `RestResource`

The initial request comes via a `RestResource` controller which is hosted on a Site which is publicly available, so therefore the permissions of the `Site Guest User` control which fields are available when the Visualforce engine processes the email template merge fields.

By giving the `Site Guest User` read permissions on a few fields, the email template now merges correctly.